# Conditionally render class or style variable

Tags: reactjs, ternary

I need to be able to set a color to a div if a variable containing a hex color value exists. If the variable doesn't have a value, it needs to use a class with backup styles.

```
const backgroundColor = backgroundColorVal;

<div className={backgroundColor ? backgroundColor : classes.divWrapperClass}>
```

What do I need to wrap the second `backgroundColor` value in to use this value inline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the background colour then.

**Set using dynamic inline-style**

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}} />
```

You can shrink the above using object literal syntax if `backgroundColor` is the same name.

```
<div style={{backgroundColor}} />
```

**Set using className**

```
<div className={`${someCondition ? 'className if true' : 'className if false'}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className={`${backgroundColor} ? ${backgroundColor} : ${classes.divWrapperClass}`}></div>
```

This would work

Answer (score 0):

you want to use style if `backgroundColor` is defined and not use class, here a solution:

```
<div style={{backgroundColor}} className={!backgroundColor && classes.divWrapperClass}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that it was simply applying the inline style and class on the same div, because the inline style will override the class if available:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor }} className={classes.divWrapper}></div>
```